# Отправка формы к стороннему сервису через API

Tags: php, api

Всем привет у меня проблема. Никогда не отправлял форму к **API**. Моя форма:

```
<form action="https://api.medelement.com/v1/appointment" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="PATIENT_NAME">
   <input type="text" name="CONTACTS">
   <input type="text" name="COMPANY_CODE">
   <input type="text" name="LANDING_COMPANY_CODE">
   <input type="text" name="APPOINTMENT_DATE[]">
   <input type="text" name="APPOINTMENT_TIME[]">  
   <input type="text" name="DESCRIPTION">    
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

А также имеется доступы к сервису. Вопрос такой, как я могу отправить форму и куда мне выставить логин и пароль для формы? 
Когда я отправляю с такой формой у меня выдает ошибку 401. Тоесть не авторизовался. Мне нужно куда то затолкать логин и пароль.

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Вы ж и так указали куда отправлять данные в атрибуте `action`

Comment: Добавить `input` не?

Comment: О каком API речь?

Answer (score 0):

Что бы отправлять что-то на API, нужно знать что это вообще такое.
В вашем случае есть полное описание методов API https://api.medelement.com/docs/index.html
и первый же метод https://api.medelement.com/v1/appointment который говорит вам о том что для того что бы авторизироватся, вам необходимо отправить хедер с именем Authorization и base64 value (SomeUser:SomePass).